# How do I add more gas to transaction in the Ethereum Wallet?

Tags: transactions, mist, gas, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm trying some things out in the ethereum wallet but it keeps guessing the amount of gas wrong. How do I send more gas in the ethereum wallet?

Comment: Which Ethereum wallet are you using?

Comment: Ethereum-Wallet Previously known as Mist I guess

Comment: Mist Ethereum Wallet usually sets gas on the most commonly used value. If you try to lower it you may run out of gas but if you leave it on the default value you're OK. Raise it if you want to speed your transaction and please miners.

Comment: I think you might be referring to the gas price not the amount of gas you allow the transaction to be used. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: No I'm really talking about selecting the amount of fees as you can see on https://goo.gl/images/0wBeUO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe it is possible from the UI that the mist wallet provides. You will need to go commandline and use the geth tool. Then you can just unlock your account and perform a transaction and define the amount of gas you want to send.

RPC doc related to function **sendtransaction** : https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sendtransaction